# Filter sub list

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I have a Realm set up so that a company has a list of locations and each location has a list of contacts. I need to be able to let the user search by zip code and filter out contacts that match.

What I've tried so far is

```
let companies = realm.objects(Companies.self).filter({$0.locations.filter("ANY contacts.zip = \(userZip)")})
```

but it tells me that `filter`can't accept argument String.

What I need it to return when it's all done is the list of companies that have locations that have contacts that match the given search. Is there an easier way to get to that then how I'm going about it?

Answer (score 0):

You intended to call the `filter()` method inherited from the Collection protocol. To call Realm's `filter()` method, you need to write as follows:

```
realm.objects(Companies.self).filter("ANY locations.contacts.zip = %@", userZip)
```

FYI: Please do not use string interpolation to construct queries. String interpolation causes unexpected behavior when the string is optional. Use `NSPredicate`'s substitution syntax instead.